# ANOVA power calculation

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, statistical-power

**Context**

I ran an experiment with a two-factor within-subjects design (factor A with 3 levels (small, medium, large) and factor B two level (open, closed), so 6 test condition).
12 subjects have repeated 5 times each of the six test conditions (so 30 test per subject).

I tested for significance using a repeated measures ANOVA (and for significant main effects, I used Scheffé post-hoc tests).

**Question**

A reviewer asked me to provide power values for my ANOVA results.
How i can calculate this values? I tried with:

- G*Power: cannot do power analyses for repeated measures designs with more than one within-subject or between-subject factor;
- R pwr.anova.test: only balanced one way ANOVA.

Comment: You can use simulation ...